# Getting hi-res audio output to my DAC

Tags: sound, display-resolution, flac

I would like to play my hi-res FLAC files in Linux through my DAC and tried outputting through a USB cable, but no matter what audio program I use, the stream my DAC receives is always reduced to CD quality. I have tried this in different versions of Ubuntu and Mint on two different laptops, and the results are always the same. I was able to get a hi-res stream on one laptop by installing Volumio, which is based on Debian, but I would like to do it with Ubuntu. I see no settings anywhere to tell the OS not to downsample the audio. My Android phone and Windows laptop send these files to the DAC with no problems at all. Any suggestions for fixing this in Linux for someone who's not super proficient with the command line?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you currently running? Are you sure a USB port and cable can give you the stream you want?

Comment: How are you making this determination objectively? "CD quality" is considered lossless with a bitrate of 1411kbps. Especially if the FLACs were ripped from a CD, what reduction in quality is there? Keep in mind that most people do not perceive any improvement in quality over a 320kbps compressed mp3. If you are making this determination based on what you hear, do you seem to be missing any particular frequency ranges? I consider myself an audiophile and recognize that it takes training and serious equipment to distinguish files at high bitrates. What DAC and equipment/speakers are you using?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. The port is a UCB-C, the same type as my Android phone, and my phone can output files up to 192kHz/24bit to my DAC with no problem. To the question of how I'm making my determination objectively, I have a Musical Fidelity MX-DAC, which tells you what the stream coming in is. So, say, if I play a 192kHz FLAC file on my phone, the DAC tells me it's coming in at 192, but when I play the same file through my laptop with the same cable, it says it's coming in at 44.1kHz. I have a stereo that can reveal the difference, so this does matter to me.

Comment: Also, Ive tried playing the files with different software that claims to play hi-res files, so I'm pretty sure it's something in the OS.

Comment: I was able to partially solve this problem by using the Audacious audio player. Rather than the default Pulse audio, I selected ALSA output device, then clicked the Settings button and chose "PCM device: hw: CARD=M20,DEV=0-MXDAC USB Audio 2.0, USB Audio (this is my DAC) Direct hardware device without any conversions." Now I can play my hi-res FLAC files through my DAC.I still don't know how to stream hi-res audio through Qubuz. Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Edit the pulseaudio config file

```
vim /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

Add to the end:

```
default-sample-format = s24le
default-sample-rate = 96000
alternate-sample-rate = 44100
resample-method = soxr-vhq
avoid-resampling = yes
```

then run with your user (not with `sudo` or as root):

```
$ pulseaudio -k
```

With this config you should be able to use your dac with a 24b/96kHz rate
Try and let us know!

For resample-method: to find out what's available you can run `pulseaudio --dump-resample-methods`

Comment: This resulted in no audio output as written; however, when I removed the " avoid resampling = yes" line, it worked, outputting at the 24bit/96kHz rate as I was hoping. I haven't extensively tested this yet to see what it does with other rates.

Comment: The "no audio output" could be caused by the fact that the source was in regular sample rate. Try to switch **default** and **alternate** rate, a recent DAC should have auto res switching:

`default-sample-format = s24le`
`default-sample-rate = 44100`
`alternate-sample-rate = 96000`
`resample-method = soxr-vhq`
`avoid-resampling = yes`